# Rotate sprite and bring to original position in cocos2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have an aeroplane sprite (consider a paper plane, pointing towards right direction), which rotates up a little when tapped on the screen, and after that, rotates back down the same amount of degrees by which it rotated upwards. I have accomplished this by using the following code:

`-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`
`{`

```
//Plane move up on touch
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
[plane stopAllActions];


[plane runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.15 angle:-20],
                 [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(0,location.y)],
                 [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.15 angle:20],
                  [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:
                   ^{
                       [self startDownMovement];

                   }],nil]];}
```

And then

`-(void)startDownMovement {
[plane runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(0,-plane.position.y)],nil]];
}`

**The problem is:** If I tap for example 2 times, the plane moves up by 20 degrees twice, but rotates down by 20 degrees just once only. I only want the plane to rotate up by 20 degrees, no matter how many times the screen has been tapped, it should stay up by 20 degrees and then come back to 0 degrees.

Please help.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: take one boolean, make it true when you first time tap and make it false when plan resets at 0 degree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works by checking the current rotation of the plane at every tap. if it is != 0 then do not rotate further, rather just keep going up. And then at `startDownMovement`, Set the rotation to 0. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Read the current rotation attribute of plane.

```
//float currentRotation = plane.rotation;
//Calculate new Rotation Value :
// float newRotation = currentRotation - offset;  (offset in your case  = 20)
//Use CCRotateTo  in place of CCRotateBy
[plane runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:0.15 angle:-20],
                 [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(0,location.y)],
                 [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:0.15 angle:20],
                  [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:
                   ^{
                       [self startDownMovement];

                   }],nil]];}
```

Comment: Not working. I tried your code but still my plane keeps on rotating if I click multiple times.